# Render time increasing exponentially each frame

Tags: cycles-render-engine, bezier-curves, motion-blur

I’m trying to render out a complicated scene, with motion blur, depth of field, volumetrics and lot of vertices.

When rendering image sequence, the render time drastically increases from frame to frame; for example, the first frame would be 4 minutes, the next 13, and the third 50 minutes. When I render just a single frame, the same one which took 50 minutes, the render time drops back to 4 minutes.While the scene is heavy, I’ve already rendered out multiple sequences which used practically the same assets, without encountering this issue.

I’ve tried finding similiar threads and came across this one from 4 years ago, which was seemingly caused by curves. Unfortunately I’m unable to get rid of all the curves, since I use Launch control addon which needs at least one curve object to fucntion properly (baking the animation also wasn’t succesfull, for some reason baking is broken for me in 3.5, as it bakes only every other frame).

Has anyone else come across similiar issues, and did anyone by any chance find any solution?

The PC specs shouldn’t be an issue; RTX 3090, 64 gb ram, i7 13700K

Answer (score 0):

Update; I was able to resolve this issue by appending all the objects into new Blend file. As to what caused this, I have no idea, as no particular object seems to be the reason.

Comment: You could try to investigate the issue to hunt for a bug: remove half of items (materials, objects, textures...) and see if the issue persists. If not, revert the changes (menu File->Revert), and remove the other half of the items, and see if the issue persists. Then you can recursively repeat this process, trying to remove as much stuff as possible. This may make you figure out the combination of stuff that causes the issue, or at the very least prepare a minimal file to share with others, so they can continue hunting for the bug. Cheers!